# AngularJS modules + Webpack + ES6 imports - Problem with dependency injection & concat order

Tags: angularjs, webpack, dependency-injection, import, module

## Problem Summary

I am migrating an old AngularJS application to use Webpack and I am splitting it into three parts, which I want to represent as AngularJS modules:

- src-ts-admin
- src-ts-common
- src-ts-store

For example I'd like 'src-ts-admin' to consume services from 'src-ts-common', but unfortunately webpack bundles files in the wrong order for AngularJS Dependency Injection, so that I end up with errors like ..

`Error: "[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: filterServiceProvider <- filterService <- initializerService`

.. where **initializerService** is a service from src-ts-admin and **filterService** is from src-ts-common. The core of the problem is that

- module("ADMIN").service("initializerService") executes before
- module("COMMON).service("filterService")

.. although I cannot spot the problem in the dependencies.

## File Overview

#### src-ts-admin: app.ts

This is the webpack entry point, however not so interesting. The application routing will trigger app.initializer.ts.

```
import angular from 'angular';
import { appModule } from './app.module';
```

#### src-ts-admin: app.module.ts

```
import angular from 'angular';
import commonModuleName from '../src-ts-common/common.module';

var modulezz;
modulezz = [commonModuleName,'ngRoute', 'ui.router', 'ui.multiselect', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.bootstrap-slider', 'ui.bootstrap.buttons', 'duScroll',
            'ngMessages', 'colorpicker.module', 'angular-bind-html-compile', 'pascalprecht.translate'];

export var appModule = angular.module("ADMIN", modulezz);
export default appModule.name;
```

#### src-ts-admin: app.initializer.ts

```
import angular from "angular";
import appModuleName from "./app.module";
import { filterService } from "../src-ts-common/service/filter-service-model";

export class InitializerController {
    static $inject = ...etc...
    constructor(...etc...) {

    /* THIS IS KICKED OFF BY AN ANGULAR ROUTE, THIS KICKS OFF THE InitializerController BELOW */

    }
}
angular.module(appModuleName).controller("initializerController", InitializerController);

export class InitializerService {
    static $inject = ["$stateParams", "$window", "$timeout", "filterService", ...etc...];
    constructor(private $stateParams, private $window, private $timeout, private filterService: filterService, ...etc...) {

        /* THIS IS WHERE THE DEPENDENCY INJECTION FAILS */

    }
}
angular.module(appModuleName).service("initializerService", InitializerService);
```

#### src-ts-common: common.module.ts

```
import angular from 'angular';
export default angular.module("COMMON",[]).name;
```

#### src-ts-common: filter.service.ts

```
import angular from "angular";
import commonModuleName from '../common.module';

export class filterService {
    static $inject = [];
    constructor() {
    /* ...simplified... */
    }
}
angular.module(commonModuleName).service("filterService", filterService);
```

#### My thoughts

The error I get is ..

```
Error: "[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: filterServiceProvider <- filterService <- initializerService
```

.. which indicates to me that app.initializer.ts is executed before filter.service.ts, although it is importing that file.

Do you see any obious errors I made? Do you have any best practices to structure AngularJS + Webpack module imports and cut files?

## --- Solution (Update!) ---

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/59631154/5244937 I could solve my problem. The pattern I should have used was to initialize the angular modules (e.g. `angular.module(commonModuleName).service("filterService", filterService);`) in the `app.module.ts` and `common.module.ts` files and NOT together with their class implementations.

Here the corrected files:

#### src-ts-admin: app.ts

```
/* here i am more or less just kicking off the angular application after i import app.module.ts */
import { appModule } from './app.module';

appModule.run(["$rootScope", "$location", ...,
    function ($rootScope, $location, ...) {
  ..
}

appModule.controller('appController', ['$scope', ..,
    function ($scope: any, ...) {
  ..
}
```

#### src-ts-admin: app.module.ts

```
/** here (1) i am initializing all angular controllers, services, factories from the ADMIN package & (2) importing the COMMON module  */

import angular from 'angular';
import ngRoute from 'angular-route';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';
import 'angular-messages';
import 'angular-translate';
import dptCommonModuleName from '../src-ts-common/common.module';

var modulezz;
modulezz = [dptCommonModuleName, ngRoute, uiRouter, 'ui.multiselect', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.bootstrap-slider', 'ui.bootstrap.buttons', 'duScroll',
        'ngMessages', 'colorpicker.module', 'angular-bind-html-compile', 'pascalprecht.translate'];

export var appModule = angular.module("DPT", modulezz);
export var appModuleName = appModule.name;

/**
 * Services
 */
angular.module(appModuleName).service("systemParameterService", systemParameterService);
angular.module(appModuleName).service("statisticsService", statisticsService);
angular.module(appModuleName).service("deletionCheckService", deletionCheckService);
...
```

#### src-ts-admin: app.initializer.ts

```
/** here i have removed (1) the import of angular.module.ts and (2) the initialization of angular controller and service "initializerController" and "initializationService" */

import angular from "angular";
import { filterService } from "../src-ts-common/service/filter-service-model";

export class InitializerController {
    static $inject = ...etc...
    constructor(...etc...) {

    /* THIS IS KICKED OFF BY AN ANGULAR ROUTE, THIS KICKS OFF THE InitializerController BELOW */

    }
}

export class InitializerService {
    static $inject = ["$stateParams", "$window", "$timeout", "filterService", ...etc...];
    constructor(private $stateParams, private $window, private $timeout, private filterService: filterService, ...etc...) {

        /* THIS IS WHERE THE DEPENDENCY INJECTION FAILS */

    }
}
```

#### src-ts-common: common.module.ts

```
/* here i have added the initialization of the angular service filterService and all other services, factories, .. contained in that module */

var moduleName = angular.module("DPT.COMMON",[]).name
export default moduleName;

angular.module(moduleName).factory("filterModel", function () { return filterModel; });
angular.module(moduleName).factory("filterPresetModel", function () {return filterPresetModel;});
angular.module(moduleName).factory("productModel", function () {return productModel;});
angular.module(moduleName).factory("propertyProfileModel", [function () {return propertyProfileModel;}]);
angular.module(moduleName).factory("propertyValueModel",function () {return propertyValueModel;});
```

#### src-ts-common: filter.service.ts

/** here i have (1) removed the import of common.module and (2) teh initialization of angular.module(..).service("filterService", ..) */

```
import angular from "angular";

export class filterService {
    static $inject = [];
    constructor() {
    /* ...simplified... */
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, how are you able to import `import angular from "angular"`. I am having challenges importing angularjs v1.3.7

Comment: @Orson You need to install angular types: `npm install @types/angular`[1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/angular)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dependencies are **inverted**, `Module` should import its deps (other modules or filters / services / components).

If you will follow this, your `AppModule` will import its child modules, which in it turn will import its services.

That means that your services should **only** export the class.
The relevant Module should import the service class, and register it on the module & export the Module name.
The parent Module should import its child Modules.

```js
// serviceX.js

export class serviceX {
  static $inject=[];
  ...
}
```

```js
// childModule.js

import {serviceX} from './services/serviceX.js';
import {componentY} from './components/componentY.js';
import angular from 'angular';

export default angular.module('childModule', [])
.service('serviceX', serviceX)
.component('componentY', componentY)
// ... rest of the childModule deps
.name;
```

```js
// appModule.js

import {externalDep} from 'external-dep';
import childModule from './modules/childModule';
import angular from 'angular';

const appModule = anguler.module('appModule', [externalDep, childModule]).name;

angular.bootstrap(document, [appModule]);
```

Comment: You are right. Together with the tutorial below, I have corrected the structure of the imports and files.

http://angular-tips.com/blog/2015/06/using-angular-1-dot-x-with-es6-and-webpack/

I'll update my original post with my current state